# Sudden 403 Error on Text Detection

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I was working with the standard example code for the text detection API and everything was working fine, but now if I try to run the same program (no edits made) on a new image, python returns the error:

> Http Error for /Users/lummish/Documents/Cloud Vision Tests/foodman.jpg 
>   < HttpError 403 when requesting https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?alt=json returned "Request Issue Failed.">

Which in turn causes the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'

I can't seem to figure out what's going on. I've tried getting a new keypair as well as cloning the project from scratch, but neither accomplished anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a curl request on your image to ensure your api key is valid etc

Comment: How do you do that?